# How Do I Embed A YouTube Playlist That Is Synchronised To Same Spot For All Users?

Tags: youtube, web, embed, playlist

So I'm trying to set up a website where I  have a long YouTube playlist that goes around in a loop. Every person who visits the site needs to see the same thing at the same time. So for example if visitor A is watching video #100 3 minutes in then so is visitor B. The reason I need this is that I want people who visit the site to be able to chat with each other about what they see at the same time. There are websites that offer this service (http://www.ldrmagazine.com/blog/2013/12/18/8-ways-watch-videos-together-synch/) but I don't know how to embed that technology into my website. By the way I only need one video, I don't need to grant users the ability to set up their own streams. I'm decent at Java programming and know the basics of XHTML and CSS but I'm no web developer... yet. What's the easiest way to do this? What do I need to learn?